# How to change default directory of localhost

Tags: localhost

My computer is in a local area network and I have installed zpanel (with apache, php and mysql as stack) on windows 7.
Suppose my LAN ip is `192.168.15.58`. Now if anyone type `http://192.168.15.58` in browser's address bar of other computer's web browser of the LAN, it is redirected to C:/zpanel/panel/index.php which is ultimately zpanel login page.
I want to change this directory to another so that no one can see the login page of zpanel (from other computers of LAN), instead they will be redirected to index.php of that custom directory.
How to do that?
Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the server gets a request for a non existant domain it will serve up the login page. It is not advisable to attempt to change this as it could prevent access to zadmin.

Zpanel/apache is showing the login page becuase it needs a valid TLD request to understand which vhost to serve up so it will always show the login page if you just enter the ip address of the server. If you are implementing an intranet you will either need to utilise a hosts file on the client machines or DNS on the server and use the server name instead of the ip address to contact the server.

Login to zpanel zadmin , add a domain, eg: local.lntranet and create a new working directory. Put your html into the new directory. On you client machines add an entry into the hosts file for 192.168.15.58 intranet.local. Now when the client types intranet.local into the browser the server will be able to determine which domain to serve, ie your intranet.

Comment: How is DNS related to the issue the OP is experiencing?